# JSON data showing duplicates when pushed to DOM

Tags: jquery, html, json

Hello newbie here trying to figure out what is wrong with my jQuery code. The code is supposed to pull Earthquake information from an API and display it in the DOM. The issue is that I am seeing duplicate information in the DOM but if I use a console call to display that info it's all unique.

HTML:

```
<div class="control-wrapper">
  <h2>Start date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></h2>
  <h2>End date: <input type="text" id="datepicker_2"></h2>
  <button id="generate">Generate</button>
</div>

<h2>Total # of EQ's: <span id="total"></span></h2>
<div class="wrapper" id="template">
  <h1>Name: <span id="title"></span></h1>
  <h3>Magnitued: <span id="mag"></span></h3>
  <h3>Tsunami Warning: <span id="tsunami"></span></h3>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var scriptString = 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=';
  var button = $('#generate');

  /**DATEPICKER**/
  var startDate = 0;
  var endDate = 0;
  $( '#datepicker' ).datepicker();
  $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd');
  $( '#datepicker_2' ).datepicker();
  $('#datepicker_2').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'yy-mm-dd');

  /** GENERATE BUTTON ON CLICK **/
  button.on('click', function(){
    startDate = $('#datepicker').val();
    endDate = $('#datepicker_2').val();
    scriptString = scriptString + startDate +'&endtime=' + endDate;
    makeRequest(scriptString);
  });
});

/** MAKEREQUEST EXECUTES AFTER THE GENERATE BUTTON IS CLICKED **/
function makeRequest(requestString){
  var myRequest;
  var eqs = [];

  var myRequest = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  myRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(myRequest.readyState === 4 && myRequest.status === 200){
      var jsonObj = JSON.parse(myRequest.responseText);//Grabs json object
      var data = jsonObj.features;
      pushToDOM(data);
    }
  }
  myRequest.open("GET", requestString, true);
  myRequest.send();
}

/** RECIEVES ARRAY OF EQS AND PUSHES THE FIRST TO THE DOM **/
function pushToDOM(eqs){
  var tot = $('#total');
  tot.text(eqs.length);

  /*ADDS EQs TO DOM*/
  for(x in eqs){
    var wrap = $('.wrapper').clone();
    wrap.attr('id', x);
    var place = eqs[x].properties.place;
    var mag = eqs[x].properties.mag;
    var tsu = eqs[x].properties.tsunami;
    wrap.find('#title').text(place);
    wrap.find('#mag').text(mag);
    if(tsu === 0){
      wrap.find('#tsunami').text('No');
    }
    else{
      wrap.find('#tsunami').text('Yes');
    }
    $('body').delay().append(wrap);
    if(x === 10){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Froy/pen/zKRkwX)

PS: The way I wrote the script seems to be an issue since it locks up the browser before displaying info so, if there is any way to improve my code structure or algorithm please let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, there are a couple of issues with your code. You need to take time and go through a few jQuery tutorials.

For now, these are the issues I have identified and fixed below.

- jQuery always applies an action to all matched elements. Therefore there is no need to initialize the datepickers individually.
- jQuery has [built-in Ajax support](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Don't use hand-rolled XmlHttpRequest code, especially don't use code you copied off of some website (This is generally true: Do not copy and paste code that you don't understand.)
- jQuery takes care of URL parameter encoding, you can pass parameters as an object, as shown below.
- jQuery does JSON parsing for you, so that is not an issue either.
- When you clone HTML elements, make sure that they do not contain any `id` attributes. IDs are supposed to be unique throughout the document, duplicate IDs break stuff. Use CSS classes to identify types of elements.
- You need to remove all previously added elements when the button is clicked a second time. This will solve your duplication issues.
- Disabling the button while the data loads is a nice touch, so is setting default values for the date fields.
- You should add some sort of error handling (see the usage of `.fail()` in the [documentation for the jQuery XHR object](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR)) to the `$.getJSON()` call.

Runnable code sample below:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
  $('#starttime').datepicker("setDate", "-1d");
  $('#endtime').datepicker("setDate", "0d");

  $('#generate').on('click', function () {
    $('#generate').text("loading...").prop("disabled", true);
    $('#total').text("");

    $.getJSON('https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson', {
      starttime: $('#starttime').val(),
      endtime: $('#endtime').val()
    }).done(function (geoJson) {
      $('#total').text(geoJson.features.length);
      $('.earthquake').remove();

      $.each(geoJson.features, function (i, feature) {
        var $item = $('#earthquake-template').clone().removeAttr("id").addClass("earthquake");

        $item.find('.place').text(feature.properties.place);
        $item.find('.tsunami').text(feature.properties.tsunami ? 'Yes' : 'No');
        $item.find('.mag').text(feature.properties.mag);
        $item.appendTo('body');
      });
    }).fail(function (jqXhr, status, error) {
      alert("Could not fetch earthquake info - " + error);
    }).always(function () {
      $('#generate').text('Generate').prop('disabled', false);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
h1, h2, h3 { font-size: small; }
#earthquake-template { display: none; }
.earthquake { border: 1px solid silver; margin-top: 5px; }
div.ui-datepicker { font-size:10px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="control-wrapper">
  <h2>Start date: <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="starttime"></h2>
  <h2>End date: <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="endtime"></h2>
  <button id="generate">Generate</button>
</div>

<h2>Total # of EQ's: <span id="total"></span></h2>
<div id="earthquake-template">
  <h1>Name: <span class="place"></span></h1>
  <h3>Magnitude: <span class="mag"></span></h3>
  <h3>Tsunami Warning: <span class="tsunami"></span></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this answer. I will definitely be going through more jQuery tutorials after looking at your code. But I failed to see an answer in your response that tells me what exactly was causing this issue in the first place, is it just terrible code structure? Thanks Tomalak!

Comment: Which issue, exactly? Does it still occur with this code?

Comment: No the code you provided works correctly. The output I was getting showed duplicate earthquake information, sometimes showing up to 4 earthquakes with the same info. Your example shows each earthquake info without any repeated.

Comment: Maybe because of the point #6 in the list above? Your code did not do that.